# Update Data Labels on onclick/ onmouseover events in C3 charts/ using D3 customization

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to update the data labels on onclick or onmouseover on an area chart. When I hover over an area block, the date labels should be changed ( destroy them and recreate them). Is there any option to do that in c3

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sushruthreddygade/2Loc3org

Here's the code using C3 charts :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', '2014-04-01', '2014-05-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-07-01'],
            ['data1', 190, 200, 190],
            ['data2', null,null,130, 130, 140],
            ['data3', null,null,null,null, 10, 20, 40]
        ],
            types: {
            'data1' : 'area-spline',
            'data2' : 'area-spline',
            'data3' : 'area-spline'
        },
        labels: {
                format: function (value, id) {
                    if (value === null) {
                        return ' ';
                    }
                    return value;
                }
          }, 
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) {},
        onclick: function (d, i) {
            alert('On click');
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
                    show: false
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'categorized'
        }
    },
});
```

Any advice/guidance towards the solution using c3/d3 charts would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Sush